# Should I use a many-to-many or one table with boolean flags in this situation?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a `properties` table and each `property` can have many `amenities`.

Examples of `amenities` are "hasTerrace", "hasGarden" and "hasPrivateParking". **There are about 50 amenities**.

The list of `amenities` is unlikely to change in the future. I see two options:

1. Add boolean flags to the `properties` table for the 50 or so fields such as "hasTerrace".
2. Create separate tables called `amenities` and `property_amenity` and have a `many-to-many` relationship.

A typical use case would be querying for all properties that have any given number of amenities.

I am inclined to keep everything in one table and use booleans because:

1. The list of amenities is unlikely to change.
2. I think that my queries will be faster (probably a crap reason given all of the db tweaking that could be done).
3. My queries will be simpler.
4. I will write less code and that code will be less complex.

**However**, having 60 or so fields in a table seems a quite high.

**Which would be the best database design for the above problem?**

Comment: The second many-to-many option seems like the better option.  For one thing, querying would be less painful/costly than you might imagine.  And the first option is flawed, possibly, because if you need to add or remove an amenity in the future for any reason, you need a schema change, whereas in the second option all you have to do is add or remove some data.

Comment: There might be more, which tells you everything you need to know

Comment: This is a faq. How could it not be? Eg google your title. Please read [ask] including about researching before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When designing databases, what is the preferred way to store multiple true / false values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200063/when-designing-databases-what-is-the-preferred-way-to-store-multiple-true-fal)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
SET ('hasTerrace', 'hasGarden', ...) NOT NULL
```

50 properties will take only 7 bytes.  Setting and testing is a bit complex; see the manual.

Similarly a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` would allow for up to 64 flags in 8 bytes, but you would need to use numbers 0..63 and "shift" (eg, `1 << 22`).

With the `BIGINT` approach, you can 'easily' test for any number of the flags being on/off in a single `WHERE` clause.

I cannot recommend one versus the other without knowing what types of queries you will need to perform.